# Emgu CV, Tessdata - can't load pol language

Tags: c#, tesseract, emgucv

I've downloaded EmguCV v4.2.0 and tessdata folder with languages and pasted this folder into bin folder. In tessdata folder I have many languages, eng and pol too.

In C# I have code like this:

```
 using (ImageParser ip = new ImageParser(@"C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop 4.2.0.3662\bin\tessdata", "eng"))
 {
     if (ip.OcrImage("C:\\Users\\v-user1\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\bied.PNG") != string.Empty)
     {
         w.AddRange(ip?.Words.ToList<string>());
     }
 }
```

When I set "eng" ImageParser is created correctly, but when I change to "pol" language I get error:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you are trying to load in the tessdata file so Tesseract can reference it when trying to detect text. The method below is what I have used in the past, and it has worked perfectly fine for me. In earlier versions of Emgucv, the setVariable and whitelist feature didn't work, but I'm not sure if it was fixed in later versions.

```
  public static void LoadOCREngine(String dataPath)
  {
     //create OCR engine
     _ocr = new Tesseract(dataPath, "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractCubeCombined);
     _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-1234567890");
  }
```